# Font won't change

Tags: android, fonts

What seems to be the problem with my coding? Why won't the font change? I've already imported the font under assets/fonts folder. With this I attached together the xml and java file

**XML File**

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/txt_level1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:text="@string/level1"
  android:textSize="@dimen/txtSize"
  android:typeface="sans" />
```

**JAVA File**

```
package com.example.basichelloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class Level_1 extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_1);

    //Font path
    String fontPath = "assets/fonts/FaceYourFears.ttf";

    //Text view label
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_level1);

    // Loading Font Face
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

    // Applying font
    text.setTypeface(tf);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think Your font path should be

```
  String fontPath = "fonts/FaceYourFears.ttf";
```

Have you created another assets folder inside assets?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you print the TypeFace you loaded to the console ? Chances are that the path is incorrect, it should not contain "assets/" to my humble opinion.